# If $A \in M_n$ and $rankA=1$ then at least one column of A can be eigenvector of the matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

$RankA=1$, that means that one column of matrix A is linearly independent,and all other columns can be presented through that one column.

I proved that one of the columns can be eigenvector on the following example

$A \in M_n$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
        a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \\
        0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

because A is upper triangular matrix,eigenvalues are the elements on the diagonal, and that's $x_1=a_1$ and $x_2=0$.For $x_2=0$ we can see that first column is eigenvector of A.

But with that one example,I can't prove that is true for every $A\in M_n$.I was wondering how to prove that for every $A$?

Comment: If $x$ is a nonzero column of $A$, then $Ax$ is in the column space of $A$ so it's a scalar multiple of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $rank(A)=1$, then wlog, we can write $A$ as
$$
A=[a_1,a_2,...,a_n]=[a_1,\beta_2a_1,...,\beta_n a_1]=a_1[1,\beta_2,...\beta_n]
$$
where $a_1\neq \bf 0$ and $\beta_2,...,\beta_n$ some real number.

plug it in the equation
$$
Ax=\lambda x
$$
we get
$$
a_1[1,\beta_1,...\beta_n]x=\lambda x
$$
let $\lambda=[1,\beta_1,...\beta_n]a_1$
then $a_1=x$.